# How to redirect an https domain to another https domain without change url

Tags: .htaccess

I have 2 website on ApacheWS:

https://1site.com and https://2site.com

I need to redirect with htaccess first domain to second domain without change url.
So if someone visits my first site, he can see my second site but the url don't change.

Any solution please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using apache `mod-proxy` . If proxy module is enabled on your server then   you can use `P` proxy flag in RewriteRule  to proxy requests between two domains.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

References :

Apache mod_proxy

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

mod-rewrite P|proxy flag

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p